# Traverse through directory printing output to file using constructors

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

ok, so i have dabbled in java, C++, python, BASIC, shell, PERL, and batch... i am trying to traverse through a directory recursively save the output to a log file for later viewing. how ever, im running into the issue of class construction in order to add a bit of intelligence and more control to the actual program i am running Ubuntu 14 and using ruby 2.0.0 now i am quite the ruby noob but im trying jump headfirst into it like i did with batch and all the others. here are the errors i am getting:

> test.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')'   @watch =
>   watch
>            ^ test.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_then, expecting keyword_end     File.file?(f) then "F"
>                         ^ test.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_then, expecting keyword_end    File.directory?(f) then "D"
>                              ^ test.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end       else "?"
>           ^ test.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

here is the code i am trying to build off of:

```
#!/bin/ruby
require 'find'
class MegaWatch
attr_accessor :written

#create a place holder in a file to log to about
#new files written to the disk.
def initialize(watch = Find.find('./')  
 @watch = watch
end

def search_dir
if @watch.nil?
puts "is empty!"
elsif @watch.responds_to?("type")
@watch.each do |watch|
  File.file?(f) then "F"
  File.directory?(f) then "D"
  else "?"
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
go = MegaWatch.new
go.search_dir = "/bin/"
end
```

any help would be loved!! the reason im doing this is because i found several.... shotty files on my disk, and i would like to add more command and control over my system. if there is an easier language to do this in any suggestions would be much loved, only having real expertise in batch the switch is a bit... difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that in ruby, unlike other languages, you don't use this "if" format:

```
if arg then
    exp
elseif arg then
    exp
end
```

Instead ruby uses this format:

```
if arg
   exp
elseif arg
   exp
end
```

Also some of your code does not make since.

1. In your "initialize" method you forgot the closed parentheses.
2. In your @watch.each loop you forgot to close the loop. Add "end"
   before your else statement
3. Try an clean up your code, indentations go a long way in helping
   others read and understand your code; especially when asking for
   help.
4. I'm not 100% for sure what you are trying to do, but if you are
   trying to return a letter based on what type of file or directory is
   being pulled then try this code.

   ```
   Path = "C:/users/owner/desktop" 
   @array_files = Array.new
   @array_directories = Array.new

   def search_dir path

       Dir.foreach(path).each do |filename|
           @array_files << filename if File.file?(filename)
           @array_directories << filename if File.directory?(filename)
       end

       return @array_files, @array_directories

   end


   puts search_dir Path
   ```

As far as figuring out if the file was made today, you might be in for some trouble.
On different platforms time of creation is stored differently. However here is how to do it on windows. P.s. This is not the best code chunk possible, it could be modified for speed, resources, efficiency, readability, and robustness; however, I am just trying to get you on the right path. You might want to split parts up into methods or classes to better the code.

```
require 'date'
Path = "your/path/here"
@today = Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
files_today = []
users = []
    Dir.foreach(Path) do |filename| 
        files_today << filename if (/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/.match(File.ctime(filename).to_s).to_s.strip == @today)
    end
puts files_today
```

On to the second problem. I had trouble figuring out how to pragmatically find who created what files but with some searching and maybe some gems or system calls you could puzzle a working script together. Nevertheless this code should start you off on getting a list of users to compare file creators to! *You may need to add to the list of users you don't want to find.

```
users = []
    Dir.foreach("C:/Users")do |username|
        users << username if !username.match /[.|..]/
    end
puts users
```

Comment: thank you so much! i was kinda beating my head against my keyboard trying to figure it out. but all the tutorials i have been reading are very.... generalized, and a google search brings a whole host of stuff. but ill give that a shot. thanks!

Comment: the goal i was trying to achieve was a by name list of every file created that day and the origin of that file down to user name date and program used to create that file, a spider for my own computer.

Comment: GOT IT!!! ill post my code into my edit on my answer. 

cant thank you enough for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

ok @schylar so i gave this a shot. it resulted in an actual log for me to review. how ever, theres more issue now. when i set the path(s) to watch, all it did was print the output of the script as /bin/ im trying to find a way to change this. here is the code im using now.

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

print "which directory?"
Path = gets.to_s
@today = Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
files_today = Path
users = []
output = File.open("./directory_log.txt","w")
    Dir.foreach(Path) do |filename| 
        files_today << filename if (/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/.to_s.strip == @today)
    end
output << files_today
```

ok, so i did lots of digging, thank you stackoverflow for the plethora of knowledge within your pages! i love you lol. but here is the code i ended up using:

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

Path = "/"
@today = Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
files_today = Dir['*'].sort_by{|f| File.mtime(f)} + Path.split(',')
users = "root, guest"
output = File.open("./directory_log.txt","a")

    Dir.foreach(Path) do |filename| 
        files_today << filename if (/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/ == @today)
    end

output << files_today
output << "\t\n\n\n\n\nScript ran at #{@today}\n"
output << "\n--------------------------------------------\n\n"
output.close
```

the output i was able to retrieve from the script in a readable log file is:

> ["Untitled Document", "tutorial.zip", "java tutorial",
>   "253721-bigthumbnail.jpg", "run.pl~", "run.pl", "directory_log.txt~",
>   "directory_log.txt", "test.rb~", "test.rb", "/bin/"]
>
> Script ran at 2014-09-09
>
> ---

figured i would put what i figured out, on here for future reference. thanks again man for your pointers!!

--